# Linkedin Social Action API Related

Tags: java, linkedin-api, spring-social

#LinkedIn
Greeting to all,
I have a question regarding Social Actions API, Basically I wanted to know that there is an particular API for getting all number of Posts along with data like (comments or like) on are linkedin Page? (Please Share an Proper Example [this is demo API which we are using https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/urn:li:ugcPost:xxxxxxxx/])

Basically, our target is that to getting all numbers of posts which are present on my linked page plus we wanted to check also that if we received a comment on my any post so how we can reply on against him using an linkedin API's

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for some of the Marketing APIs. There is a [Posts API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2023-01&tabs=http#find-posts-by-authors) that would allow you to search for posts by author. There is also a [Social Actions API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/network-update-social-actions?view=li-lms-2023-01&tabs=http) to get numbers of comments and likes. Note that you need to be [approved to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/quick-start?view=li-lms-2023-01) these APIs.