# linkdin api v2 - how to get like comment count in posts/shares list

Tags: json, api, linkedin-api

i'm fetching all posts of a user urn from LinkedIn shares/posts API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2023-01&tabs=http#find-posts-by-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api?view=li-lms-unversioned&tabs=http

in response i'm getting array of this object. **How can I fetch want like and comment count in this object list**.

```
 {
        "owner": "urn:li:organization:31060",
        "activity": "urn:li:activity:702717776",
        "edited": false,
        "created": {
            "actor": "urn:li:person:uMD-5FNQoE",
            "time": 1675400404262
        },
        "distribution": {
            "linkedInDistributionTarget": {
                "visibleToGuest": true
            }
        },
        "content": {
            "shareMediaCategory": "RICH"
        },
        "clientApp": "urn:li:developerApplication:3710791",
        "text": {
            "annotations": [],
            "text": "A lot of our clients "
        },
        "id": "70271386165857",
        "lastModified": {
            "actor": "urn:li:csUser:0",
            "time": 1675400404332
        }
    },
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? If you want such data available through the API, you probably need to contact the maintainers of that API

Comment: I've tried contacting them but cant find any platform. I wanna know if this is possible cant find anything in there doc page.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75293329/linkedin-social-action-api-related

Comment: Thanks, @Ashavan for the link, but that question does not answer my question. It looks like they have not made it possible to do so. So I have to fetch all the social actions with batch social actions API. which has 2 API calls on every fetch